# How to solve system with 4 equations and 7 unknown variables?

Tags: systems-of-equations, problem-solving

I have system of 4 equation, this is part of work for experiment in fluid dynamics, where with two known variables I need to determine other unknown variables. Known variables are:

$n, m, \beta, K$

and equations are:
$$\beta \varepsilon = \dfrac{\kappa M^2}{R}$$
$$\gamma \varepsilon^m = \kappa M^2$$
$$\eta \varepsilon^n = K$$
$$K = \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi \kappa}{2}} \dfrac{M}{R}$$
from these equations I can get next relationships, which are checking point for me,it means if I get some values from the first four equation I check it in next relationships:
$$\gamma = \dfrac{\beta^2 \pi}{2 \eta^2}$$
$$R = \dfrac{\gamma}{\beta}\varepsilon^{m-1}$$
so it is necessary at least to determine $K, M, R$, and if it is possible determine and all other variables.

With known variables, for example $n = 0.25, m = 0.75, \beta = 1, K = 0.1$
 I always get result as one variable is missing, it means I get all results in  terms of one variable, for example $\varepsilon$. If I put one more variable as known, system is redefined, because results which I get from the first four equations are not the same when I check it with other two equations.

How can I solve this system?

Comment: Is $K\,n=K \times n$ ?

Comment: No, it is one variable. I edited notation.